# emacs filecache wont let me create new file buffer

Tags: emacs

I enabled filecache by (require 'filecache) in my init.el. it is convenient until i was trying to make a new file buffer that uses similar file name.

Say, i once edited a file "../path1/foo.txt", now i want to create a new file "../path2/foo.txt", emacs won't allow me to do that, it insists that i want to open "../path1/foo.txt". No matter that i manually  pressed C-x C-f and input the full path for the new file, Emacs just automatically jumps to the existing file in minibuffer, and i just could not make my new file.

do i have to disable filecache in such case?
thanks

Comment: Did you add any other configuration for filecache in your init.el? Normally, filecache only operates if you hit C-TAB to expand from the file cache, and if you are just typing and hit return, it is not invoked.

Comment: not really, that is the other thing i dont understand, i use emacs24.3 in win7, i also enabled ido mode as:  

 '(ido-enable-flex-matching t)
 '(ido-enable-last-directory-history t)
 '(ido-everywhere t)
 '(ido-mode (quote both) nil (ido))

is that causing the problem of autocomplete behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ido is the cause here.

It looks like ido-find-file won't let you create new files. It does allow you to escape back into normal find-file by hitting `C-f`. That should let you create the files.